# How the two RewriteRule combined into one?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two Rewrite code lines:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/meishi/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=1
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/meishi/([0-9]+)/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=1&page=$2
```

How can I combine the two `RewriteRule`s into one?

Comment: The trailing `/*` means zero or more `/` at the end of the request. Is this the intended behaviour or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having a blank `page=` at the end, you can combine the two rules like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/meishi(/([0-9]+))?/*$ index.php?city=$1&category=1&page=$3
```

Comment: Thanks!It works! Php script must be added this line:
    if($page==0) $page=1;